# Python: How to save output files to a directory?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run `HSPICE`(A circuit simulator) in python script, and save output files to a directory named `dic`.

```
import os
os.system("hspice example.sp > result.lis")
```

HSPICE will generate other files such as `result.mt`, `result.st`, etc.

Is there a command in `python` that can save the output files to the directory `dic`?

The method I can think of is to look for files starting with `result`, copy them to the directory and delete.

Comment: why not simply use os.system("hspice example.sp > dic/result.lis") ? or you could do os.system("mv result* dic/.") after executing hspice.

Comment: @Alejandro It gives me an error `-bash: dic/result.lis: No such file or directory`

Comment: this is because you have to create the directory dic first. With python you could import os and add the following line at the beginning:  if not (os.path.isdir("dic")): os.system("mkdir dic")

Comment: Oh please use python function instead of calling shall command.

Comment: @Alejandro Yeah it works. TY!

Comment: Try to use python function instead of using os.system().

Comment: @Hun is right.  Use `os.mkdir("dic")`, not `os.system("mkdir dic")`